# Having some trouble with Tkinter Treeview and SQLite when trying to search for a name in a database

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, treeview, tkinter-entry

I have successfully been able to click a search button on my tkinter GUI and have the results display in my treeview however if I want to search straight again I get an error because when trying to write for the second time it's writing to the same row as the first search query. How would I either clear the treeview or make sure that my program writes to the next row in my treeview?

```
srchEntry = str(searchEntry.get())
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT memberID, fullName, username FROM Test WHERE fullName ='"+srchEntry+"'")
conn.commit()
data = c.fetchall()
treeview.insert("", 0, 1, values=(str(data[0][0]), str(data[0][1]), str(data[0][2])))
```

So 'data'  will return ('memberID', 'fullname', 'username') and I am inserting those values into my treeview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read doc [Treeview.insert](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.insert).

`insert()` has parameter `index` to choose row. Or you can use word `end` to put after last row.

---

`delete()` needs `id` of inserted row/item (not row number)

```
item_id = treeview.insert(...)
```

and later

```
treeeview.delete(item_id)
```

Comment: when i try and assign item_id to treeview.insert(...) it says 'local variable 'item' value not used.